# Scale a sidebar based on window width

Tags: css, sass

I have a sidebar that I want to be 200px wide when the window is 620px wide, and 240px wide when the window is 938px wide. The window will always be between 620 and 938px. I would like the sidebar to scale between 200-240px based on the window width. I have a JavaScript solution that sets the sidebar width everytime the window is resized, but I'm wondering if there is some way to do this with CSS or SCSS. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with @media queries ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries ) ?

Comment: It's the scaling that is the hard part. I could make 40 media queries for every window width between 620 and 938 where the sidebar width would change, but that seems silly. Using a percentage for width won't work either because 200px is 32% of 620 and 240px is 26% of 938.

Answer (score 1):

Define all lengths of your sidebar in vw units and so it will scale with your window.

So instead of

```
aside { width: 200px; }
```

you will have

```
aside { width: 32vw; max-width:240px; }
```

That will give you `~200px` on `620px` window and `200..240` on larger windows.

Comment: Sidebar needs to reach 240px width as window width reaches 938, so unfortuneately `vw` isn't precise enough. I'm upvoting anyways though, because I think this would work for a lot of people trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: "needs to reach 240px width as window width reaches 938" it will do precisely that as `min( 938px * 0.32, 240px) == 240px`

Comment: Hm... Maybe I'm misunderstanding or not explaining myself well. `width: 32vw` leads to the sidebar reaching 240px when the window is 750px wide, and I want the sidebar to not reach its max width of 240 until the window is 938px. At window width 750px, I need the side bar to be at 216px wide.

Comment: So you have non-linear windowWidth->scale relation, right? What formula describes scale factor then?

Comment: `240 - ( 40 * ((938 - currentWindowWidth) / 318))` That's finding the percentage the window is currently at between 620 and 938, multiplying it by 40 to get the offset and subtracting that from the maximum width of 240.